# Including fstream or ifstream in a C++ Header File

Tags: c++, header-files

How does one go about defining methods in a header file that accept either an fstream or ifstream as a paramater?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class hw4
{

        public:
                // Methods
                char* cFlagCheck(char* logfile, fstream& f);
                int sFlagCheck(char* set, fstream& f, ifstream& cpy, int &R, int &X, int &Y);
                void* runRobot(void* robotCount);
};
```

Comment: Do you mean, how to declare a method which would accept `either` an ifstream or an fstream as one of it's arguments? For example, you wanted to be able to call cFlagCheck with either an fstream or an ifstream as the 2nd argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prepend the class names with the `std` namespace ie. `std::ifstream`